# Fit Hawkes process to 1d data using python package TICK

Tags: python, goodness-of-fit, fitting, point-process, hawkes-process

How can one fit the 1-dimensional Hawkes process with exponential kernel to 
 the experimental 1d dataset (t1,t2,t3...tn) and check the goodness-of-fit 
via [tick python3 package](https://x-datainitiative.github.io/tick/index.html)? 
I found on official webpage that

> This module proposes a comprehensive set of tools for the inference
>   and the simulation of Hawkes processes, with both parametric and
>   non-parametric estimation techniques and flexible tools for
>   simulation.

But I didn't found there any example how to fit the Hawkes process to the real (non-simulated) 1d temporal data.

Answer (score 3):

the `tick` module only allows you to estimate your Hawkes process for a fixed value of the decay $\beta$ for an exponential kernel $\phi(t) = \alpha \beta \exp (-\beta t)$. This is because estimating jointly $\alpha$ and $\beta$ leeds to non convex, poorly scalable algorithms.

However, you can try several values for $\beta$ and keep the one that gives you the best score. Here is an example of this procedure on a finance dataset.

```
import numpy as np
from tick.dataset import fetch_hawkes_bund_data
from tick.hawkes import HawkesExpKern
from tick.plot import plot_hawkes_kernel_norms

timestamps_list = fetch_hawkes_bund_data()

best_score = -1e100
decay_candidates = np.logspace(0, 6, 20)
for i, decay in enumerate(decay_candidates):
    hawkes_learner = HawkesExpKern(decay, verbose=False, max_iter=10000,
                                   tol=1e-10)
    hawkes_learner.fit(timestamps_list)

    hawkes_score = hawkes_learner.score()
    if hawkes_score > best_score:
        print('obtained {}\n with {}\n'.format(hawkes_score, decay))
        best_hawkes = hawkes_learner
        best_score = hawkes_score

plot_hawkes_kernel_norms(best_hawkes, show=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

i found it very frustrating that all the samples i found in the tick doc used simulated data which i couldn't use to effectively understand how to feed real data in.  i had to run one of their simulators in a debugger and look at the timestamps output. None of the examples I've found even mentioned the data type required in the timestamps.  --you want a list of ndarrays of dtype float64, so convert your timestamps lists to that first.--
i found [this post](https://nathankjer.com/hawkes-python/) helpful for modifying those timestamps, particularly the following code segment:

```
start_time = min([min(timestamp) for timestamp in event_timestamps])
end_time = max([max(timestamp) for timestamp in event_timestamps])
event_timestamps = [(timestamps-start_time).astype(int)/86400e9 for timestamps in event_timestamps]
```

and then you can just feed the `event_timestamps` into the `fit()` function